# Best way to instantiate an Android Room Entity object for insertion without specifying the autogenerated PK? (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

In Android, when using the Room database and using an auto-generated primary key, your pk will be a field of the object and therefore will need to be set when you create a plain-old Kotlin object. So what is a correct and clean way to instantiate an object that you use *for insertion*?

Say you have a table like so:

```
@Entity(tableName = "data")
class Data(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) @ColumnInfo(name = "id") val id: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "some_data") val someData: Int
)
```

If you want to actually insert a `Data` object, you will need to specify the `id` at initialization.

I see two possibilities, and am unsure if either are correct:

- Assign it a dummy value. Will Room generate a real one for you when it actually inserts it into the database?
- Change the field type to be `Int?` and always set its value to `null`.

Comment: "Assign it a dummy value" -- `0` works. "Will Room generate a real one for you when it actually inserts it into the database?" -- you can have your `@Insert`-annotated function return a `Long`, and that will be the auto-generated ID.

Comment: Ok great, then I will assign a dummy value. I think a clean way to deal with instantiation is to create a static factory that will set the the `0` dummy value and get the rest as input.

Answer (score 1):

If within a Dao have :-

```
@Insert
fun insertDataRow(data: Data): Long
```

- Thus the id of the inserted row will be returned

and then use

```
insertedId = myMado.insertDataRow(0,10)
```

The **insertedId** will be the generated id.

If you use **Int?** then you could use

```
insertedId = myMado.insertDataRow(null,10)
```

If with **Int?** if you used (with no existing data)

```
insertedId = myMado.insertDataRow(0,10)
insertedId = myMado.insertDataRow(0,11)
```

The you would get a UNIQUE constraint exception for the second insert as the **id** is set to 0.

That is there is a subtle change if you use **Int?** as opposed to **Int**. **Int** effectively treats 0 as null whilst the **Int?** treats 0 as the value 0

- P.S. ideally you should use Long or Long? for the **id** as it can be a 64bit signed integer.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
@Entity(tableName = "data")
class Data(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) @ColumnInfo(name = "id") val id: Long = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "some_data") val someData: Int
)


fun generateData(name: String): Data {
    return Data(name=name)
}
```